# Let $f: (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function, and $(a,b)$ contains the origin.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f: (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  a function, and $(a,b)$ contains the origin.

Prove that if $f$ is monotone and $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {f(x)-f(-x)}{x}=0,$$ then f is differentiable at $0$.

I tried to add and subtract $ f (0) $ at the top, in two separate limits and use the lateral limits, but I can not guarantee that they exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Hint:* Since $f$ is monotone, we have $|f(x)-f(0)| \le |f(x)-f(-x)|$.

> Therefore $0 \le \left|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\right| \le \frac{|f(x)-f(-x)|}{|x|} \to 0$, as $x \to 0$, i.e. $f'(0) = 0$.